# Submit an app with In App modules

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am a newbie in Windows Store Apps development. I have created an app which has some In-App purchase modules. I am testing this with locally created WindowsStoreProxy.xml file, However to test in app purchases, I updated this xml manually and added these modules in ListingInformation and LicenseInformation tags. If I don't do this my app throws KeyNotFoundException which is usual. Now my issue is, after submitting the app to the app store how will testers test these in-app purchases? Its very serious, because It may cause to App Rejection. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Store dashboard, you'll fill out the in-app purchase details before you submit. All that info will then be in the Store database when the testers get your app.

To be specific, when uploading your app you'll take whatever information you've been using from WindowsStoreProxy.xml and paste it into the app description page. If you want to see what this looks like, go ahead and create an app package now, and then upload to the dashboard. This will then allow you do go to the description page where you can see what will be required. Just make sure to upload a new package before you complete the submission.

Also be sure to change CurrentAppSimulator to CurrentApp (you'll fail cert quickly if you forget).

Comment: Thanks, I assumed the same and uploaded the App.